Nuxt 3 says "variables" is undefined while I have defined it within the data, how do I fix this?
So I have a Nuxt 3 project and I have a problem with my default layout file.
In my script tag I have defined the following
export default {
        data() {
            return {
                variables: {
                    productsHover: false,
                    aboutUsHover: false,
                    applicationsHover: false,
                    customSolutionsHover: false,
                
                    mouseOverMenu: false,
                    subProductsMediaHover: false,
                    subProductsSerumReplacementHover: false,
                    subProductsWfiHover: false,
                    subApplicationsBioproduction: false,
                    subCustomSolutionsRuotogmp: false,
                    subCustomSolutionsSterileLiquids: false,
                    subCustomSolutionsOem: false,
                    subAboutUsQuality: false,
                    //width: window.innerWidth,

                    appMenu: false
                },
            }
        },

and the first element (which is also the point where the error comes) that interacts with this data looks like this:
<div class="h-full transform transition-all duration-300 z-20 w-full flex  absolute" v-show="this.variables.appMenu == true && widthStore.width < 688">

I know its this point because when I change the variable name to something else like abc the error message says  the same just with abc instead of variables.
The error I am getting:
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'variables')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     12:39:06
  at _sfc_ssrRender (C:\Users\wandres\Desktop\Nuxt\nuxt-test\layouts\default.vue:409:48)
  at renderComponentSubTree (C:\Users\wandres\Desktop\Nuxt\nuxt-test\node_modules\@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:683:9)
  at renderComponentVNode (C:\Users\wandres\Desktop\Nuxt\nuxt-test\node_modules\@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:631:12)
  at renderVNode (C:\Users\wandres\Desktop\Nuxt\nuxt-test\node_modules\@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:743:14)
  at renderComponentSubTree (C:\Users\wandres\Desktop\Nuxt\nuxt-test\node_modules\@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:698:7)
  at C:\Users\wandres\Desktop\Nuxt\nuxt-test\node_modules\@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:629:25
  at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
  at async unrollBuffer$1 (C:\Users\wandres\Desktop\Nuxt\nuxt-test\node_modules\@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:870:16)
  at async unrollBuffer$1 (C:\Users\wandres\Desktop\Nuxt\nuxt-test\node_modules\@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:875:16)
  at async unrollBuffer$1 (C:\Users\wandres\Desktop\Nuxt\nuxt-test\node_modules\@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:875:16)

When I load the page the error always gets logged in the console but on the page it self it shows the error on the first time loading, if I load it again I dont get send to an error side but the right side with everything working, the error is still logged in the terminal.
Everytime F5 the page after I have a chance off landing on a error page which shows the exact same error as the console logs or to just be on the page with everything functioning.
Does anybody understand why it appears and/or how to fix it?

You don't need to use this in the template, try to replace this.variables.appMenu with variables.appMenu
